# Minimum speed that a bike won't fall over

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics, everyday-life, applied-physics

I thought about this when riding the bike today:

What is the minimum speed I have to go that my bike won't fall over with a given angle $\alpha$ of tilt, diameter $d$ and weight $m$ of a tire (let's say the bike tilts 30 degrees at maximum when driving in a straight line and the diameter of a tire is 0.60 m with a weight of 1 kg per tire).

I guess the angular momentum of the tires has to counter the torque of the gravitational force somehow.
How can I calculate this?

Comment: Maybe this resource will be of help: http://ruina.tam.cornell.edu/research/topics/bicycle_mechanics/overview.html

Bicycle dynamics are very complicated.

Comment: People can stay upright on conventional bikes while not moving for virtually unlimited time (until they are bored or need to go to the bathroom, essentially). Forward motion is not needed to balance.

Comment: Not supposed to pick an answer after two secs , Jon C it is hard to stay up on a bike not moving

Comment: @AlBrown afaiaa the SE network imposes a minimum time limit between asking and accepting, and it's longer than 2 seconds..

Comment: *won't fall over with a given angle ... when driving in a straight line* - question is confused; there is only one angle (perfectly in line with the direction of action of the force of gravity) and infinite speeds regardless the weight of the assembly. You cannot ride a bike in a straight line, on an angle (i.e. such that the center of gravity is not over the contact point of the tires with the ground) so that it "won't fall over".. A bike that is leaning over must describe a direction of travel that is an arc, not a straight line.. not that a line on the surface of a sphere is straight, but..

Comment: @AlBrown it's called a trackstand.  It's hard, but it's possible.  However as someone who can ride extremely slowly but can't trackstand, I'd say the dynamics are rather different

Comment: Watch here... https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rNmccweyut4

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> I guess the angular momentum of the tires has to counter the torque of the gravitational force somehow. Can someone help me calculate this?

That's the peculiar thing, the angular momentum of the tires doesn't actively provide torque to bring the bike back upright. Rather, it slows down the rate at which the bike can tilt, allowing a rider enough reaction time to make the proper adjustments to keep it upright.

If you get a bike up to high speed and then just "let it go", you'll notice it falls to the ground pretty quickly, almost as quickly as if you just let it go in your garage.

**Edit**: There's a lot of discussion below about how a bike can be self correcting due to the ability to *turn* - lots of great physics in there but it's missing the point of the question, which is the correction when

> moving in a straight line

The amount a bike can precess to stay upright will depend on a number of parameters about the bike. On one extreme you have a wheel by itself, which will continue to turn until it slows to a stop and then fall. On the other extreme, you can imagine an extremely long bike with locked handle bars - it will fall to the ground quite quickly. All that would be a great answer to a separate question.

Moreover you'll notice I carefully worded my answer to say:

> the angular momentum of the tires doesn't actively provide torque to bring the bike back upright

As I wanted to give a simple answer that doesn't overwhelm someone asking a simple question at their level (but I get that everyone loves to "actually..." on this site). This statement is correct that the angular momentum of the tires will slow the tilt toward the ground but never restore the bike toward its center. That was the point.

Comment: Thanks. That makes more sense than the way I thought of it. I remember my mechanics teacher saying that parents should tell their kids to go fast and not slow because it's safer  lol

Comment: *If you get a bike up to high speed and then just "let it go" ... it falls to the ground ... as quickly as if you just let it go [with it stationary]* - i disagree; bikes can be (and are) set up so that the "falling over" causes the steering to turn more sharply than required for the given arc being described as it falls, shifting the balance of forces and bringing the bike back upright (excess torque opposing that imposed by gravity). It exchanges some of the forward momentum to do so, so starting it off at a high speed gives it ample excess momentum to perform it for an extended period

Comment: You can see in the video associated with the linked comment under the question - http://ruina.tam.cornell.edu/research/topics/bicycle_mechanics/overview.html - the human gets the ridersless bike up to a good speed before knocking it sideways. This starts a series of damped oscillations; the bike "survives" being "knocked over" and carries on (having traded some of its speed). Had that bike been stationary it would have been lying on the floor a couple of seconds later

Comment: The funny thing is that your last paragraph is definitely *not* what I would expect from experience. Obviously I haven't tested this with a real full-size bike, but I did once [build a fairly realistic motorcycle in a physics simulation game](https://kerbalx.com/vyznev/Kerley-Davidson-Mk2) and found that with proper tuning it could cruise stably for several minutes even with no control inputs or automatic stability assist. Anyway, this should be fairly easy to test by letting a (toy) bike roll down a hill. (Of course it would need to have the proper caster angle etc. to be actually stable.)

Comment: @IlmariKaronen *your last paragraph is definitely not what I would expect from experience* - that's because, IMHO, the last paragraph is not true

Comment: Other than the bit about angular momentum, this answer is not correct. A moving bike **is** a self-righting mechanism and does not require input from the driver to remain upright. A moving bike does not fall fast when let go. It only falls when slowed down enough. The principle is as follows: suppose the bike starts leaning left. Therefore, the bike _turns_ left. But inertia wants the bike to keep going forward, which forces the bike to lean more to the right, thereby cancelling the initial left lean. This is how it continually self-rights itself as long as it moves fast enough.

Comment: @juliangst Your mechanics teacher is probably making a facetious comment and has neglected to mention speed wobble which can and does affect bicycles.

Comment: I agree with @Flater. The last half of this answer is incorrect. A bike *is* self-stabilising when in high enough speed (if the steering wheel is fixed), and this is easily demonstrated by simply throwing a detached bike wheel forwards and seeing it roll - it will keep up the motion until it has slowed down enough. Then it will fall; not before.

Comment: Another demo is to simply walk a bike along lightly holding the saddle with one hand.  At a slow walk it's wobbly and you're really supporting it, but at a jog it keeps upright, though it turns towards/away from you as it does so.

Comment: @Flater that is only true if the front wheel is allowed to turn, and even then I'm not convinced that it will turn on its own, or at least sufficiently to force the bike-rider system upright.

Comment: @CaiusJard Your counter example is from your experience with *nice, high-end* bicycles. *Most* bicycles don't have this capability. I don't think either of you are wrong, but I'd wager this answer is correct in *most* cases (from growing up with cheap bikes that I know are far more common than nicer alternatives) - I think poor engineering/imbalanced parts is what makes them fall

Comment: The last paragraph is not true, this is based on extensive experiments performed by neighborhood kids during my youth. A bike, which accelerated to speed, and then left to its own devices, will continue rolling down the road a considerable ways, it will generally start to turn away from the crown of the road, and then head for the curb, where it will impact and bounce into the air, coming to rest in a neighbors front yard. This is the way we did it then, no wonder the youth of today lack an understanding of experimental physics!

Comment: Bicycles at speed **are** stable and self-righting. The effect is measurable, well-studied, and has to do with positive trail allowing the bike to self-steer to maintain stability. Here's a bit of info, besides the well-known video: https://cyclingtips.com/2018/11/the-geometry-of-bike-handling-its-all-about-the-steering/

Comment: @CaiusJard addressed your comments in the edit. It simply appears you didn't read the question nor answer well enough.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft: What I said is specifically more prevalent when the steering is **locked**, free steering complicates the effect. A good example of this effect at play is during superbike races. [Take this example](https://youtu.be/Gb6PVY2M6Ek?t=1), crash in the first few seconds. The rider is leaning to his right, but the centrifugal effect pulls him leftwards, and it managed to pull him hard enough that he cannot keep the bike on its lean. This is the exact same effect as to why a moving bike is a self-righting mechanism, only exacerbated due to the high speed and traction of those tires.

Answer (score 3):

The bike will not go straight if it is left alone and tipping. Secondly, it will tip slightly faster if not moving, but it will still tip over from any non-vertical angle whether moving or not.

---

All assumes no rider:

The right-had rule can tell you which way it’s path will curve as it tips, but your intuition will too: if leaning right the bike will gently turn right. And the handlebars/front-wheel as a unit has a lower moment of inertia around a vertical axis than the body of the bike, and hence they will turn faster.

Also, the gyroscopic “force” is just our way of trying to understand and communicate the dynamics of a spinning object when an external force is applied to its axis. The bike will tip over by itself any angle from vertical, however small, it may just take longer if moving.

Here’s one rigorous way to see the situation: the wheels are spinning and have an axis of rotation which is the same as each wheel’s axis. The direction of the vector representing the angular velocity is pointed along the axis to the left, determined from the right-had rule with your fingers going the spinning wheel’s direction, and its length determined by how fast the wheel spins.

If the bike is tipped a little, let’s say to the right, then gravity is pushing downward, and **it is displaced slightly** from the center of the wheel’s axis (displaced horizontally). That creates a torque around the very center of the wheel. We know a torque angularly accelerates something by $T = I \alpha , \alpha = I / T$ and the direction of this angular acceleration vector is, by the right-hand rule, pointed in the direction of the bike’s travel.

How will this change the angular velocity vector of the wheel. Just add vectors. It will transform the angular velocity vector (which points left) by moving it forward, and this means the wheel is spinning about a new axis and will move perpendicular to that new axis, ie bend to the right. The front wheels can turn more easily as they only have to move the wheel/handle-bar assembly.

If not moving, the torque will go entirely into rotating the bike itself about the point where the tires touch the pavement and not have to slowly bend the existing axis of angular momentum. If moving, the torque modifies the current dynamic by moving axis of rotation.

---

As an aside, the right-hand rule is an arbitrary convention; there is nothing special about right vs left. In fact, handedness is a fundamental physical parameter, which **Immanuel Kant did not realize**. He thought a hand in space away from any object or orientation would be neither right- nor left-handed https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/a/84452/53366

Comment: *That creates a torque around the very center of the wheel* - i do not agree that the center of the wheel is the point around which the bicycle assembly rotates, if that's what you're saying

Comment: I think we probably agree: “the torque will go entirely into rotating the bike itself about the point where the tires touch the pavement and not have to slowly bend the existing axis of angular momentum”

Comment: So what's the "center of the wheel" got to do with anything? The center of rotation is the contact point of tires with ground, and the rotational torque is derived from the assembly conceptually acting as if it were a point mass at the center of gravity, which isn't the center of a wheel either..

Comment: (I'm also slightly confused as to what the significance of the lack of a rider has; are you considering a rider as an active control mechanism keeping the bike upright, or as simply a weight fixed to the bicycle?)

Comment: Theres two things: one is the rotation of a bike tipping over. We agree thats around the point on the ground. But the wheel is spinning about its center (as seen from the bike). If we assume the wheel is instantaneously rotating around the point where it hits the ground (which technically is true) then it is angularly and linearly accelerating. We cant add the two rotation vectors if one is already moving. That was my thinking

Comment: The force that turns the bike is the sum of the angular velocity about the wheel center and the tipping torque which created a moment too.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/128515/discussion-between-al-brown-and-caius-jard).

Comment: I get you now; it wasn't immediately clear that you're talking about a torque applied to the wheel causing it to rotate around its hub, as separate from the torque gravity applies to the assembly causing it to rotate (fall over) around the point where the tires contact the ground

Comment: _"The bike will not go straight if it is left alone and tipping."_ There is a limit to the correctness of your statement. If the bike is moving at less than X velocity, what you say is correct. If it has more than X velocity, the bike _will_ upright itself and go straight but then overcorrect and lean the other way, repeating the process over and over. At precisely X, the bike would right itself and be perfectly balanced (which is practically unachievable of course). The value of X depends on many factors, e.g. angle of the initial lean, bike mass (and CoM height), traction, tire roundness,...

Comment: @Flater Really? Are you sure?  What mechanism would make it right itself? In the answer i added the torque from leaning to the angular momentum of the wheel.

Comment: @AlBrown: The basic centrifugal effect. From a top down view, a bike is moving forward. It tilts, causing it to turn to the right. However, inertia wants the mass to go straight. That straight-line inertia is pulling to the left **relative to the now slightly turned bike**, i.e. a perceived centrifugal force, which counters the lean to the right and "pulls the bike up". The more velocity or mass, the bigger that centrifugal pull. For sufficient momentum, the centrifugal pull can overcome the initial lean (and then overcorrect to the other side, and then repeating the process)

Comment: @AlBrown A good example here is [superbike MotoGP crashes](https://youtu.be/Gb6PVY2M6Ek?t=1), where the sudden burst of centrifugal force causes the bike to snap itself in an upright position again and effectively launches its rider in the air like a catapult. In the linked video, look closely as the sequence of events. Rider leans in, the bike's body suddenly lifts again, tossing the rider, who then loses control of the bike.